# htaccess css path relative to index.php

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess

I run `CodeIgniter` on local LAN.

Since I have Wordpress, Drupal,... and they should not conflict I need to run them as subfolder. For example:

```
http://192.168.1.101/CodeIgniter/
```

My css is placed in:

```
http://192.168.1.101/CodeIgniter/css/mystyle.css
```

In my PHP styles are addressed:

```
<?='<link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'?>
```

My problem is that as far as I load index.php there would be no problem. However, when I load a page with parameters like:

```
http://192.168.1.101/CodeIgniter/users/login
```

My browser looks for the style in relative way!

```
http://192.168.1.101/CodeIgniter/users/css/mystyle.css
```

Which has an extra **users** in path.

I want all CSS to be adjusted in relative to:

```
192.168.1.101/CodeIgniter/
```

this is the content of `192.168.1.101/CodeIgniter/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|image|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

how to fix it?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter has **[URL helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)** that assist in working with URLs.
Autoload url helper in application/config/autoload.php.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Now `echo base_url();`
returns your site base URL, as specified in config file.

Now include css like

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('css/mystyle.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: While this approach works perfectly, there's another way to fix this issue, just insert `<base href="<?php echo base_url()" />` at `<head>` section. but be aware, this will affect all relative addresses.

Comment: true. i had done that before, but i was looking for a way to get rid of absolute url to make my code look like normal websites. but it seems there is no way.